# i have written it as res.send(). so gettingTO a page with noCSS just the data written i wnat to change the CSSproperties of that page how to do that

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, response

I have written this code for weather app how to change the background and CSS properties of the page the data is getting posted

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {

    const query = req.body.cityName;
    const apiKey = "48a9ebfd3c72f0c53af5c483631e82ad";
    const unit = "metric";
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + query + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=" + unit;

    https.get(url, (response) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        response.on("data", (d) => {
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(d);
            const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;
            const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
            const windSpeed = weatherData.wind.speed;
            const pressure = weatherData.main.pressure;
            const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
            const imageUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";

            res.write("<p>Temperature  " + query + " is " + temp + "  degrees celcius.</p>");
            res.write("<p> Weather description - " + weatherDescription + "</p>");
            res.write("<p>Wind speed " + windSpeed + " Km/hr </h4>");
            res.write("<p>Pressure is  " + pressure + " mbar </p>");
            res.write("<img src=" + imageUrl + "> ");
            res.send();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing:

- What does the html page that is requesting this data look like?
- What do your current css files look like?

Comment: like what do you want to know

Comment: "how to change the background and CSS properties of the page the data is getting posted" — By writing CSS. It really isn't clear what the problem is here.

Comment: this is the html code the data we are fetching from api is being posted on other page not the home page so how i can add css to that page that <body>
    <h1 class="heading">WHAT IT FEELZ LIKE...</h1>
    <div class="container">

        <form action="/" class="form-data" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="cityName" placeholder="enter the city name" class="entrybox">
            <br><button class="btn " type=" submit ">Go</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: the api is sending response and i have written it as res.send(). so i am getting directed to a page with no css just the data written i wnat to change the css properties of that page how to do that

Comment: You're repeating yourself. If you want CSS in a page then put CSS in the page.

Comment: it is not a html page it is just being posted on page it doesnt have any path

Comment: please see the comment below maybe you will be able to understand what i am trying to say and  help

Answer (score -1):

I understand from your comments now :)
If you want to change the css, you need to add a `style` property to your html tags.

For example:

```
res.write("<p style='background-color:red;'>Temperature  " + query + " is " + temp + "  degrees celcius.</p>");
```

You can find more information here: [https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp#:~:text=try%20it%20yourself.-,Inline%20CSS,-An%20inline%20CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp#:%7E:text=try%20it%20yourself.-,Inline%20CSS,-An%20inline%20CSS)

Comment: thanks tjhis worked but the problem is still not solved . bg color red is applied to just paragraph tag but i want to apply to body

Comment: @anonymus it's the same solution, you need to add a style tag to the body in your html page.
For example: <body style='background-color: red;'>

Comment: In html i have form data only that is that is enter the city and go button. and the data i m getting on this page is fetched from the api